# Pan UImage within superview swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, pan

I'm attempting to move an `UIImageView` within its superview using the pan gesture, although I'm able to make the superview move within self.view I am not able to do move one of its subviews within itself.

These are the relevant lines in my code

```
let couponOutline = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 424))

let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceHolder"))
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 128, height: 128)
imageView.center = CGPoint(x: 230, y: 300)

couponOutline.addSubview(imageView)
self.view.addSubview(couponOutline)

let panRec = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "moveView:")
    panRec.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(panRec)
```

in the moveView: method

```
func moveView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    println("pan")

    let couponOutline = view.subviews[0] as! UIView

    print(couponOutline)

    var translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

    sender.view?.center = CGPoint(
        x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x,
        y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)

    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), inView: couponOutline)
```

I'm trying to move imageView within couponOutline, when I use this code it does not pick of the gesture at all (println("pan") is no shown).

Comment: You add gesture to `qrView`,what is `qrView `?

Comment: sorry leftover code - all fixed

Comment: any reason for not just using a scrollview ?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so the user can position the UIIMage within the coupon outline them self - I'm not familar with it, am i able to do that with a scroll view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scroll view wouldn't be useful for some of the features I plan to add, I finally found the solution - All I needed to do was set `imageView.userInteractioEnabled = true` .

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use a `UIScrollView`. Follow the tutorial linked below(go to "Scrolling and Zooming a Large Image")

[Ray Wnederlinch UIScrollView tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift)